# Merge [linking-errors] into [linker-error]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I propose merging / aliasing the [linking-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linking-errors) tag with [linker-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linker-error).

For comparison:

- [linker-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linker-error) is the more widely used tag, with 2,418 questions to date and 18 followers.
- [linking-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linking-errors) has only 120 questions tagged, no tag guidance excerpt or tag wiki, and 0 followers.

IMO, [linker-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linker-error) is a slightly better tag name, since it contains the word [linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linker), and also for being consistent with [compiler-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. (Save for caching effects.)

I went through questions tagged [linking-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linking-errors) and zapped a small pile that were talking about problems with HTML hyperlinks or database links. Several of these were already closed, others of them I had to close first. Somewhere around 5 I just retagged.

That enabled everything tagged [linking-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linking-errors) to be merged directly into [linker-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linker-error), so I did that, and created a synonym.

Oh, and I renamed [linker-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linker-error) to [linker-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linker-errors) for symmetry with [compiler-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-errors).